# Using Listener with Antlr4: How does the compiler know how to treat a variable lvalue as opposed to a rvalue?

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr4

In my grammar, variables start with the $, so

```
$a = 10
```

is valid. Of course, so is the following statement:

```
$c = $a + $b
```

My grammar treats variables with this (partial) definition;

```
start: (expr | stmt)* EOF ;

stmt
    : lvalue=id EQUAL assignexpr=expr # AssignId
    | declare EQUAL assignexpr=expr #DeclareAndAssign
    | declare # DeclareVar
    ;

expr
    : sign=(PLUS|MINUS) expr # signed_expr
    | LPAREN expr RPAREN # paren_exp
    | id # idval
    | value #constval
    | lvalue=expr op=(PLUS | MINUS | MULT |DIV) rvalue=expr # arith
    ;
```

Up until now, when I encounter a constant value in my listener, I simply issue an ICONST (assuming it's an integer) which pushes the value to the stack. When I get to a variable, I issue an ILOAD to grab the variable value and push it to the stack - which is fine as long as it's on the right side of a statement.

The problem I have is: when the variable is on the left side .. I need to not issue an ILOAD because the value is going to be overwritten and not popped from the stack at any point. So upon reaching this variable in code, I need a way of knowing how it's going to be used.

How can I know how to treat this variable $c? Do I need to change my grammar to more specifically treat this case? Do I need to walk the tree twice? How do people usually treat what must be a trivial, common case?

Comment: What exactly does "When I get to a variable" mean? I'd assume it'd mean either when `enterIdval` or `exitdval` is called. But in that case, I don't understand your problem because the `Idval` listener methods won't ever be called when a variable is on the left side of the assignment.

Comment: You're absolutely right .. I made a stupid mistake - I was listening for ExitId instead of ExitIdval. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you clarified in your comment, you're listening for `id`s, which is used by both assignments and variable expressions. If you listen for `idval`s instead, you'll only get variables that are used as expressions / rvalues.

You can handle variables as lvalues directly in the listener for `AssignId`.